# Latitude & Longitude from Web services

Tags: iphone, gps

i am making an application in which i have to show current location(the location which is clicked by camera)using latitude, longitude through web services on Google map  & nearest location to the current location. i have done with showing current location, now i have to show which location is the nearest to location to current location. we have to find out nearest using latitude & longitude from web services. i don't know how to pick from web services. so, if anyone has solution.....Plz help me. Thanx in advance

Comment: For future reference: it's "please", not "plz", and "thanks", not "thanx".

Answer (score 2):

[This tutorial](http://www.mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/) will show you how to use CoreLocation on the iPhone.

The first two posts on [this forum](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/1634-corelocation-services-convert-long-lat-city.html) have the information about using the longitude and latitude to find the nearest city/street/etc...

Answer (score 1):

This is a horribly formatted question.  Please break this massive paragraph down into smaller paragraphs. I really do not get what you are asking. Maybe number the steps you are trying to do and what the issue is at each step.

Some *possible* answers is that you could use the iPhone 3.0 Mapkit which will allow you to embed maps. Or MKReverseGeocoder which will take a latitude and longitude point and convert it to the address of the nearest place mark which is pretty neat.

John.